# What is the least torment in Jahannam?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jahannam

I want wanted to share this with the community as it sometimes wonders my mind

> What is the least torment in Jahannam?

The hadith of Numan ibn Bashir

> I heard the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) say: the least suffering for the inhabitants of Hell on the Day of Resurrection would be for the man under whose soles would be placed two embers and his brain would boil on account of them. [Source/Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:213a)

The hadith of Samra bin Jundab

> There would be among them those to whom the fire will reach up to their ankels and to some of them the fire would reach their knees and to some it would reach their waists and to some it would reach up to their collar-bones. [Source/Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2845b)

If anyone could provide more information on this matter will be thankful.

**NOTE:** the 2nd hadith is translated sorry I couldn't find it in English if anyone could provide it with the source will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the least torment in Jahannam?

Comment: But, you already answered that question with a quite clear hadith...

Comment: @TheZ as I mentioned in the first sentence I wanted to share this info and in the last sentence *If anyone could provide more information on this matter*

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.222160412.526206637.1633838219-768141999.1627734979)

Comment: You are supposed to ask a question in the question post, and answer in an answer. You answered in the question...

Comment: will fix it thanks

Comment: This looks like a clear misuse of the "editing" option. It doesn't make sense if you ask a question and edit it once an answer is posted this is disrespectful for the people who do research and spend their efforts in order to answer your inquiry!

Comment: @Jamila as you can see the above converstion not my choice

Comment: Well your question could simply be edited with the addition that you want additional information this is how almost anybody except with theZ understood it. But what you've done now is a big mess. @theZ the ahadith might be clear in their translation in Arabic somemore input would be helpful.

Comment: The initial question without any edits was understandable, it would have been better with a few minor edits but this edit has gone all wrong. Posting a part of the question as an answer, maybe the author was not fully aware of the tools and practices.

Comment: Rolled back to a rather intial state post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Asalaam alaikum**

The narration by Al nu'man ibn Bashir about the least form of punishment in jahannam is a **muttafaqun alayhi** Hadith. Meaning it is mentioned in sahih bukhari and Muslim, thus it reaches a very high level of authenticity.*[another similar narration can be found in tirmidhi as well (book 39 Hadith 36)]*

The narration by Samurah b. Jundub can be found in sahih Muslim. Infact there are two narrations with a slight difference in wording.  [ Muslim 2845a & 2845b ( book 53 Hadith 38 & 39 ) ]
*(You can find the translated text as well as Arabic on [www.sunnah.com](http://www.sunnah.com))*

**REGARDING THE LEAST FORM OF PUNISHMENT**

i have not come across any Hadith that explicitly states the least form of punishment in jahannam other than the narration by ibn Bashir. Though there are many reports about the various degrees and severity of punishments, this Hadith is the one that states the least form/punishment.

The narration from Samurah tends to give us a notion of such but scholars have given more clarity on it. I will quote what I found relevant regarding this, inshallah.

- regarding the narration of Samurah :

> Al-Haafiz (may Allah have mercy on him) said : It may be that this was narrated concerning those among the people of Tawheed who enter the Fire, and the circumstances of their punishment will vary according to their deeds. As for the disbelievers, they will be fully immersed in the fire.[ Fath al-Baari (11/394) ]

> Al-Qurtubi said, “This topic indicates that the kufr of the person who simply disbelieves is not like the kufr of a person who oppresses, disbelieves, rebels and disobeys. There is no doubt that the infidels will suffer different levels of punishment in hell, as is known from Qur’an and Sunnah. We know for certain that the punishment of those who oppressed and killed the Prophets and Muslims, and spread corruption and disbelief on earth, will not be the same as the punishment of those who simply disbelieved, but treated the Prophets and Muslims well. Do you not see Abu Talib, how the Prophet (peace be upon him) will bring him up to a shallow level of Hell, because he helped him, protected him and treated him well? The Hadith narrated by Muslim from Samurah may be interpreted as referring to the infidel, as there is a Hadith about Abu Talib, or it may be interpreted as referring to those monotheists who will be punished.” (At-Tadhkirah, p. 409)

With this we are able to have an understanding as which is the least form of punishment in jahannam. As punishments are dealt accordingly, there are all the more possibility that it can be different for the people of tawhid and others. May Allah protect us all.

**NOTE:** there are two more narrations regarding less severe form of punishments reported by ibn Haatim in his tafseer and another narrated by Al-Hakeem at Tirmidhi in Nawaadir ul-usool but i find it's not relevant to mention those in detail because those are not authentic.

May Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**Allah knows best**